# Why will React Native Picker not display on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, picker

I am trying to use the  element in React Native. It works fine on Android but is not displaying on iOS.

```
<Picker selectedValue={'java'} >
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a `height` and a `width` to your picker element

```
<Picker selectedValue={'java'} style={{height: 100, width: 100}}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Btw, the picker wont appear like the keyboard could.

Answer (score 4):

To display on iOS I needed to add a `<Text>` element with a title for the `<Picker>` and place both inside a `<View>` element

e.g.

```
<View>

  <Text>Select Language</Text>

  <Picker selectedValue={'java'} >
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>

</View>
```

I also noticed adding the `alignItems: 'center'` style to the element caused it to not display.

Comment: interestingly, `alignItems: 'center'` was the issue for me, and removing it from the parent view solved my problem of it not showing.
Adding a `width` and a `height` to the `Picker` controller is not necessary at all, from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the style @react-native-picker/picker support two different style

@platform android => it has the style props
@platforn ios => for ios itemStyle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).